# IntentService freeze when HttpUrlConnection.getResponseCode() is called

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, intentservice

I need to send asynchronously data to an Api and I am using `IntentService`. 
It freezes when calling `con.getResponseCode()`.

It didn't ALWAYS freeze, at the beginning I have sent requests to the server without problems. At a certain point it started freezing. From then it freezes everytime, like it is waiting for response but it never comes.

This is for android api from 19 and higher (I am actually running on api 24 anyway).

I have used this code in AsyncTask before and it worked (divided in `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`). This time I need something that can run in background even when the app is closed so AsyncTask is excluded.

I'm posting the code inside `onHandleIntent` of `MyIntentService` class that extends `IntentService`.

About the Api that I made for this it works fine, I've already tested it.

EDIT: I tried with `JobIntentService` but it doesn't work anyway. I'm surely missing something but I don't understand what.

```
    String ret = "";
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    DbManager db = new DbManager(getApplicationContext());

    try{

        SharedPreferences pref = 
        getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 

        String URL_STRING = pref.getString("STORED_URL_FOR_REST_SERVICE", 
        null) + "/api/values/7";
        URL Url = new URL (URL_STRING);

        con = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        con.setRequestProperty("json_input", db.getJsonToSend());
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //con.setDoInput(true);
        //con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setUseCaches(false);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == 200 || responseCode == 201 ) {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            br.close();

            ret = sb.toString();

        } else {

            ret = "ERRORE: " + Integer.toString(con.getResponseCode());

        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        ret = "ERRORE: " + e.getMessage();

    }
    finally {

        if(con != null) {
            con.disconnect();
        }

    }


    if(ret.contains("ERRORE")){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore nell'invio dei 
        dati\nNuovo tentativo a breve", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Gson gson = null;
        Rest1 r2 = null;

        try {
            gson = new Gson();
            r2 = gson.fromJson(ret, Rest1.class);
            db = new DbManager(getApplicationContext());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            db.setRowToSent(r2.getResult().split("#"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (r2.getMessage().equals("OK")) {


        } else if (r2.getMessage().equals("KO")) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore nell'invio dei 
            dati\nNuovo tentativo a breve", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```